# how to decrypt/decode this?

Tags: javascript, encryption

Im working on a challenge and have te decrypt something...
but I can't figure out what kind of encryption it is.

```
<script>

function decrypt(inp) {
result = "";
for (var i=0; i<inp.length; i++) {
    result = result + String.fromCharCode(inp.charCodeAt(i) ^ "ENCRYPTED".charCodeAt(i %  9));
}
return result;
}

/*
 * Use this function to verify the security code
 */
eval(decrypt("O8& 06-eye(6<:$=**ef-'4|t61&-&!*yt>Nencr06tm07;&ryvrel+;.rp\u0019$0-  `3=.xfidugjrxmtudchcz7%9ebe\u0003\"&1~$*3m|orhy}eyxnsrvtm*0#cty\u001d51,k>,%qbxevlgcsdpdebcnk<,=tcd\b\/7:w ;2lwbcapytdye~ctp|+1(ner\u00141 -j5!4zk|tqmln~oy`tcbef-'4pre\t$:+|)?#mvinv{ppixdunetyx:0)ehc\u001f8$<k4*9k`upblmeo~riprcdm 6?yvt\b%1&m\"6'|wheyj{yqieteherq>!(dcn\u000e3-8z5+2fq~yh}lddscbyvrel+;.rp\u0019$0-`3=.xfid|gjrxmtudchcz7%9ebe\u0003\"&1~$*3m|orh`}lddscbyvrel+;.rp\u0019$0-`3=.xfidtj{ymieteherq>!(dcn\u000e3-8z5+2fq~yaflmes~riprcdm 6?yvt\b%1&m\"6'|whep{ppixdunetyx:0)ehc\u001f8$<k4*9k`upeqmln~oy`tcbef-'4pre\t$:+|)?#mvinrgpytxye~jr\"Z]L7 :\u0017;45;00m=61:5'6hesbiyoOM8n&>*5t>NLG\/=:1 ,++`175?5!lluI[$Z)OM"));



var enabled = true;
function handle() {
if (!enabled) {
    return;
}
if ($("#code").val().length >= 4) {
    verify(parseInt($("#code").val()), function() {
        var code = $("#code").val();
        $.post("/unlock.php", 
            { code: code, step: 3 },
            function(data) {
                if (data == "OK") {
                    document.location = "/4";
                } else {
                    $("#code").val('');
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

}
j

this is a part of the source-code.
Is there anyone who can tell me how I can decrypt this?
I did found this... but Im not sure if It is necessary.

/* jquery.utils.js: various simple utility functions - 2k12 CS 
 */

(function($) {

```
$.extend({

    postJSON: function(url, data, callback) { return $.post(url, data, callback, "json"); }, 

    base64_decode: function(input) {

        var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + 

            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

        var output = ""; var chr1, chr2, chr3;

        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4; var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);

            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);

            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);

            if (enc4 != 64) output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

        return output;
    },

    format_time: function(value) {

        var minutes = Math.floor(parseInt(value) / 60);

        var seconds = parseInt(value) - minutes * 60;

        if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;

        if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;

        return minutes + ':' + seconds;
    },

    // return value seperated with dashes every $groupsize characters

    seperate: function(value, groupsize) {

        var splitexp = new RegExp(".{1," + $.xn(groupsize) + "}", "g");

        var trailexp = new RegExp("[^-]{" + $.xn(groupsize) + "}-$", "g");

        var groups = value.replace(/-/g, "").match(splitexp);

        if(!(groups)) return ""; 

        var result = groups.join("-");

        if(value.match(trailexp)) result += "-";

        return result;
    },

    debug: function(message) {

        if(typeof(console) == "undefined") return false;

        return console.log("[portal] " + message); 
    },

    xh: function(value) { 

        return value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;')

               .replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/`/g, '&#96;');
    },

    xn: function(value) { return Number(value); }, 

    xw: function(value) { return value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/, '_'); }, 

    xclass: function(value, allow_spaces) {

        allow_spaces = allow_spaces || false; 

        if(allow_spaces) return value.replace(/[^ a-zA-Z0-9_-]/, '_');

        return value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/, '_');
    },

    xu: function(value) {

        return encodeURIComponent(value).replace(/!/g, '%21')

            .replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28')

            .replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/`/g, '%60');

    } });
```

})(jQuery);

I've anybody could tell me how to decrypt this would be great!

Comment: As I can see it's just a XOR cipher. It's a custom cipher that you won't find in jQuery or any other library. Don't expect we found the solution at your place, the goal of challenges like this is justly to found the solution yourself.

Comment: The reason for custom cyphers like this is that you have to actually do work and figure out the pattern yourself without using a library

Comment: I don't want to know the solution, I want to find out. but am not really in to javascripts / encryption. so if you could tell me which part triggered you for XOR would be nice

Comment: Ok, no problem: this part `...inp.charCodeAt(i) ^ "ENCRYPTED".cha...`

Comment: and can u give me a hint to decode it? because it looks like I need a "key"

Comment: Hint: if `a = b ^ c` then `b = a ^ c`

Comment: doesn't ring a bell yet.. try to google for it i guess

Comment: I can't tell you more without telling you the solution, sorry.

Comment: I tried, and tried but just don't get it... if you would give me the answer.. ill try to see what im doing wrong